# C# Random.Next(min. max) return value less than min

Tags: c#, random

Does anyone have any idea why does this piece of C# code return `x = 0` and `y = 0` (ocassionally) :

```
public void NewPos() 
{
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    while (lstPosition.Where(z => z.Position.X == x && z.Position.Y == y).Count() != 0) {
        x = new Random().Next(4, 20) * 10;
        y = new Random().Next(4, 20) * 10;
    }

    NewPos.X = x;
    NewPos.Y = y; 

    Console.WriteLine(x + "  -  " + y );
}
```

Comment: Just a heads up, you should use the same instance of `Random` in this case. As is, it is *very* likely that `x` and `y` will be the same number since the two Random instances will have the same seed. As for your bug, that doesn't seem possible based on the code that you've shown (or there is a bug in `Random` - which is unlikely).

Comment: @vcsjones I used the same instance, but 0 0 kept showing up, so I change to this. By the way, my main question is why does the Next() function return a value less than the min value that I provided? Thanks

Comment: I would guess that it's a circumstance where the above two lines don't actually run, even though you currently believe that they did. Impossible to tell from just this code though.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever It runs, the first result was OK, the second always 0, the third is not, the 4th will be 0 and so on ....

Comment: Where `x` and `y` are used? Could you provide *more* code to analyze?

Comment: After a few million iterations I never once got the value 0.

Comment: what is type of x and y?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I edited the code

Comment: @EagerToLearn `Random` isn't broken. You don't need two instances. If there is a problem, identify and solve the problem instead of trying random changes

Comment: So, if there's any item in your list with a position of 0,0, the `while` loop never runs at all and so you get the result observed. How are you sure that's  not true? Also, don't *count* if all you care about is existence or not - use `Any()`.

Comment: Obviously your while evaluates to false in certain scenarios.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever OH , I got it

Comment: Thanks alot, I got it now...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not ever getting inside the while loop, although we can't tell what `lstPosition` is set to with the code you've provided. The where clause must be returning an empty set.

There's no way [Random.Next(int, int)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4(v=vs.110).aspx) is returning zero in this situation.

Presumbably, you want to initalize `x` and `y` to a non-zero value.

Answer (score 2):

You, probably, want something like this:

```
// Do not recreate random 
// (otherwise you're going to have a badly skewed values); 
// static instance is the simplest but not thread safe solution
private static Random s_Generator = new Random();

public void NewPos() {
  // Just Any, not Where + Count
  if (lstPosition.Any(z => z.Position.X == x && z.Position.Y == y)) {
    // If we have such a point, resample it 
    NewPos.X = s_Generator.Next(4, 20) * 10;
    NewPos.Y = s_Generator.Next(4, 20) * 10; 

    // Debug purpose only
    Console.WriteLine(x + "  -  " + y ); 
  }
}
```